# Passing variables to replace wildcard on laravel Route?

Tags: laravel, redirect, routes

I'm middle of practice laravel , basic lesson 11th on laracast, wondering that if I create an entity from form page like below

```
<html> blahblah..
..
<form method="post" action="{{ Route('customModel.store') }}">
    forms.. many forms..
</form>
..
</html>
```

When I submit this form, data will flow through the router.

```
Route::post('/customModel', [
    'as'=>'customModel.store',
    'uses'=>'CustomModelController@store
]);
```

The CustomModelController has its method named store and problem is here..

```
public function store( Request $request )
{
    $CustomModel = CustomModel::create([
        'name' => Request('name'),
        'desc' => Request('desc')
    ]);

    // Here is the PROBLEMMMM..
    return redirect('/field/'. $CustomModel->id );
}
```

It feels really... mm... weird using redirect function directly and attach some variables directly to fill wildcard value.

Is there other ways to replace `redirect()`?

Something like do something with `Route` or another?

Comment: Is it the helper function you don't like or concatenating the wildcard value?

Comment: You could do `return app()->make("ControllerYouWant")->methodYouWant($CustomModel->id)` but just because you could doesn't mean you should

Comment: m.. I think concatenating the value is what I don't like.. because it feels like, there exist a better and simple way to do this. Does it exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `route()` method of `Illuminate\Routing\Redirector` class as:

```
return redirect()->route('route_name', ['id' => $id]);
```